# Best way to check if argument is a filename or a file containing a list of filenames?

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I'm writing a Perl script, and I'd like a way to have the user enter a file or a file containing a list of files in $ARGV[0].

The current way that I'm doing it is to check if the filename starts with an @, if it does, then I treat that file as a list of filenames.

This is definitely not the ideal way to do it, because I've noticed that @ is a special character in bash (What does it do by the way? I've only seen it used in $@ in bash).

Comment: The '@' character is not special to a shell. It's just one of the special parameter names, just like '?' in '$?' for the exit status of the last command. This is the reason why you will see it exclusively used as '$@'. In all other circumstances the shell does not give it any meaning. In particular you can use it as the first  character in a file name just fine.

Comment: read first line of file and check if it is a valid filename?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify additional parameter on your command line to treat it differenly e.g.

```
perl script.pl file
```

for reading **file**'s content, or

```
perl script.pl -l file
```

for reading list of files from **file**.

You can use [getopt](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) module for easier parsing of input arguments.

Comment: Definitely a good idea. This is what `wget` does, for example - `wget url` or `wget -i file-containing-list-of-urls`.

Comment: I recommend [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) rather than [Getopt::Std](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html).  It does pretty much everything Getopt::Std does, plus a lot more (particularly long option names like `-list file`.)

Comment: I'm currently using Getopt::Long for the other options in the script. I write all my scripts in this environment with the first argument as a bare filename, which is why I'd like this functionality. I suppose to do it the way I'm doing it I'll have to chose another uncommmon character, one that doesn't get auto-escaped on tab completion.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "using how about Getopt::Long for the other options in the script", but it's possible to shift off the first element of `@ARGV` and use `Getopt::Long` on the remaining args, so your call would be:  `perl script.pl file -l`.  Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

First, you could use your shell to grab the list for you:

```
perl script.pl <( cat list )
```

If you don't want to do that, perhaps because you are running against the maximum command line length, you could use the following before you use `@ARGV` or `ARGV` (including `<>`):

```
@ARGV = map {
   if (my $qfn = /^\@(.*)/s) {
      if (!open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)) {
          chomp( my @args = <$fh> );
          @args
      } else {
          warn("Can't open $qfn: $!\n");
          ()
      }
   } else {
      $_
   }
} @ARGV;
```

Keep in mind that you'll have unintended side effects if you have a file whose name starts with "@".

Answer (score 0):

`'@'` is special in *Perl*, so you need to escape it in your Perl strings--unless you use the *non-interpolating* string types of `'a non-interpolating $string'` or `q(another non-interpolating $string)` or you need to escape it, like so

```
if ( $arg =~ /^\@/ ) {
    ...
}
```

Interpolating delimiters are any of the following:

- `"..."` or `qq/.../`
- `` `...` `` or `qx/.../`
- `/.../` or `qr/.../`

For all those, you will have to escape any literal `@`.

Otherwise, a filename starting with a `@` has pretty good precedence in command line arguments.